# What does 'leaving a little puff of blue in the air' mean?

Tags: phrases, literature, idiom-meaning

In the book I am reading (H.G. Wells' [*The Invisible Man*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ov9zCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT128&lpg=PT128&dq=Adye+leapt+backwards,+swung+around,+clutched+at+this+little+object,+missed+it,+threw+up+his+hand+and+fell+forward+on+his+face,+leaving+a+little+puff+of+blue+in+the+air.&source=bl&ots=zdWla26wTM&sig=CDF__6ULiltS6uWCR7RM_fSqpTc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMI2uGVlu3hxgIVBnOOCh1NWw-R#v=onepage&q=Adye%20leapt%20backwards%2C%20swung%20around%2C%20clutched%20at%20this%20little%20object%2C%20missed%20it%2C%20threw%20up%20his%20hand%20and%20fell%20forward%20on%20his%20face%2C%20leaving%20a%20little%20puff%20of%20blue%20in%20the%20air.&f=false)), a man was shot and the scene was being described, then I met the following sentence:

> Adye leapt backwards, swung around, clutched at this little object, missed it, threw up his hand and fell forward on his face, ***leaving a little puff of blue in the air***.

Adye is a policeman and was shot by the invisible man while trying to take a gun from him.

What does 'leaving a little puff of blue in the air' mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the smoke that came from the now invisible revolver.

> The revolver vanished, flashed again into sight, vanished again
>
> H.G. Wells' The Invisible Man

[image]

Comment: This, after 'maelstrom'?

Answer (score 2):

Cursing was sometimes called **tuning the air blue** so it is possible the fellow said something foul as he fell.

Comment: If H. G. Wells didn't intend this pun, it's a damn shame! In any event, you've installed it and I love it!